# Local windows user needs password reset every month - how to prevent?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Win 2016 server VM on Amazon where created a local user as:

```
net user newguest newguestpwd /ADD /PASSWORDCHG:No
```

and this user is for authenticating to MS SSAS. But once in a month I need to reset its password:

```
net user newguest newguestpwd2
net user newguest newguestpwd
```

Otherwise my MS SSAS customer can't login with a cryptic error message.

Last time I had suck a lock up, I run the following command found on some forums, and it said Ok,False,False.

```
get-wmiObject -class win32_userAccount | select-object -property status,lockOut,disabled*
```

At this moment I run out steam, as I am a complete noob in Windows administration.

How to prevent this account from necessity to cycle its password every so often?

Comment: In Powershell, since you tagged that: `Set-LocalUser -Name “myuser” -PasswordNeverExpires 1`

Comment: ok, thanks, how do I check current state of it?

Comment: Check out the `Get-LocalUser` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable Password Expire Policy for specific user.
Run below command with administrator privilege :

```
wmic UserAccount where Name='username' set PasswordExpires=False
```

But if you need powershell command, you must run below command:

```
Set-LocalUser -Name "username" -PasswordNeverExpires 1
```